# Add multiple markers with add addresses in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I am getting familiar with how mapbox works, I am taking addresses from a database that I put in the query of mapboxClient.geocoding
.forwardGeocode, but it only takes the last address that is in my database. I need bookmarks to be added for every address I have. I would appreciate if you could help me or assure me. I have the following code:

Views.py

```
def direcciones_view(request):
    direcciones = INSTITUCION.objects.filter(ins_estado='1').order_by('ins_comuna')
    template_name = "Map.html"
    context = {'direcciones': direcciones}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Map.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Add a marker using a place name</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/es6-promise@4.2.4/dist/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/umd/mapbox-sdk.min.js"></script>
{% block content %}
{% if direcciones %}
{% for direccion in direcciones %}
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidmVuZ2Vyc3RlaW4iLCJhIjoiY2toM3A1anR3MDlqeDJzcGZ3bWpvam80YyJ9._vy6lsgCwzYfgkEXnBQ8fw';
var mapboxClient = mapboxSdk({ accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken });
mapboxClient.geocoding
.forwardGeocode({
query: "{{direccion.ins_comuna}},{{direccion.ins_direccion}},Chile",
autocomplete: false,
limit: 1
})
.send()
.then(function (response) {
if (
response &&
response.body &&
response.body.features &&
response.body.features.length
) {
var feature = response.body.features[0];

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
center: feature.center,
zoom: 10
});

new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(feature.center).addTo(map);

}
});
</script>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The template system looks like Django or Ninja2.

If you use `for` template like this;

```
{% for direccion in direcciones %}
<script>
...
</script>
{% endfor %}
```

This will be expanded to below;

```
<script>
...
</script>
<script>
...
</script>
<script>
...
</script>
```

Therefore the results are overwritten by the succeeding scripts and you only see the last result.